# PHP Select Date Column from SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, date

I am having some trouble getting a date field out of my SQLServer using PHP and have not been able to Google a solution. I know that it involves the fact that the field is a date data type in my table, but the only results I get is a 500-Internal Server Error.

Here is what I have:

```
$query = "SELECT EntryDate FROM Table1 WHERE UserID = 1";

$result = sqlsrv_query($link, $query);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo $row['EntryDate'];
}
```

This works with every other column in my table except the date column. Any idea why?

BTW, the date in my table is formatted as yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Did you check your error log? What caused the `500` response?

Comment: I am very new to PHP and only use it as a go between for a PhoneGap iOS app and our SQL Server. How can I view the error?

Comment: Try putting this at the top of your script <?php ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ?> That should print errors to the browser

Comment: Thanks. This is what I got:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row['entryDate']
```

seems to be an object of type DateTime which you can't print out directly. Try to convert it into a string in order to echo it.

```
echo $row['entryDate']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or

```
echo date_format($row['entryDate'], 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[PHP: DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: I used echo date_format($row['EntryDate'],'Y-m-d') since my data type is actually date, not datetime, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Your variable doesn't include the time but its type is still datetime. Those kinda things are important to know when searching for an appropriate method/function for the type. Thats why I linked the PHP page in ;-)